# What is the idiom or proverb or phrase for this "hard packing but loose knot"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, proverb-requests

What is the idiom or proverb or phrase for this "hard packing but loose knot"?

For example, you took hard preparation for the exam, but, didn't attend it.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that ***[it was all for naught](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+naught)***:

> without achievement or result
>
> *I spent a long time preparing for my test, but it was all for naught.*

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: Or, "All for nothing" :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're asking, but you could say that all of your hard work was **in vain**.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+vain